# How can I send data to java Server from the XML-RPC client in Python?

Tags: java, python, xml-rpc

I have created a XML-RPC model (with server and client) written in Python.

But I want to send data from Python rpc client , and  get the data in java rpc Server.
But how can I call the java methods in Python? I cannot creat a handler
in my Python XML-RPC client.....

Comment: You defined a endopoint in your java server? Once you have the methods in the java server, you need to make a requisition to them. In python, you can use requests

Comment: I have no idea for that ,can you give me a demo ?Thanks !

Comment: I have never worked with Java backend, so I cant give you a demo on that. But you can look for SpringMVC. Its the java framework for web development. The python client will be the easy part, as you can make a web request with one line of code